No closed form for integrating an exponential times lognormal PDF?
I am trying to solve the following integral, which is an exponential PDF in time that multiplies a lognormal PDF for the rate constant k. This is a Bayesian approach to solving the Albery model for chemical kinetics.  I've tried the Feynman approach, using Mathematica (lol), expansion of $\exp(-kt)$ as a Taylor series, and nothing works! Here's the problem (integrating with respect to $k$):
$$ \int_0^{\infty} \exp(-kt)\exp\left[-\frac{(-\log(k)-m)^2}{2s^2}\right] dk . $$
If it wasn't for the $\exp(-kt)$ the integral is easily derived. With it, it seems impossible! Thx,

What makes you think that it is non-convergent? Do you rather mean that you find no closed form for it?

Thanks for writing - yes I meant there is no closed form. Mathematica just repeats the input shown below, regardless of whether the integral is definite or indefinite. My other lame attempts such as the Feynman method failed. Expanding the $\exp(-kt)$ into a series produced a non-convergent series as a result. Here is the mathematica input:  (Integrate[
Exp[-kt]/Sqrt[2Piss]Exp[-(-Log[k] - micro)^2/(2s*s)], {k, 0,
Infinity}, Assumptions -> {t > 0, s > 0, micro > 0}])

(Edited) It is known that the Laplace transform of a Lognormal distribution does not have a closed form: https://data.math.au.dk/publications/thiele/2013/math-thiele-2013-06.pdf
By the way, you have an extra minus sign before $\log(k)$.

Thanks! I was able to use that reference to derive an approximate answer, it worked well!
